# Apply CSS hover just on visible part of a clipped image

Tags: css, hover, clip-path

```css
.circle {
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(120px at center);
          clip-path: circle(120px at center);
}

.circle:hover {
  cursor:move;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/10000/nahled/2185-1265776088aCTz.jpg" alt="" class=" circle">
```

Is there a way to have hover just apply on the visible part of the image?

Comment: I believe you will end up with a workaround solution. One of them is that you can put another div over your part of the image and set the cursor you like for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only what I can see to make it work is to add a wrapper element and apply the clip to that but the hover state to the inner element.

```css
.wrapper {
  display:inline-block;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(120px at center);
          clip-path: circle(120px at center);
}

.circle {
  display:block;
}

.circle:hover {
  cursor:move;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><img src="//placehold.it/300" alt="" class=" circle"></div>
```

Comment: OMG! It works!!! The only solution which worked on Safari. The rest browsers work fine without wrapping